# Need to report on temp table space usage in an Oracle 12c database

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

is there a way generate a report on historic usage of temp table space in an Oracle 12c database?
SQL statements have been failing on this database and we have already increased the size of the temp table space to 200GB; the SQL statements are not failing any more but the developer(s) would like to see such a report. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Diagnostics pack installed and  historic AWR collection enabled you can get this information from a couple of places:

1. DBA_HIST_TBSPC_SPACE_USAGE displays historical tablespace usage statistics.
2. since  11GR2 use  dba_hist_active_sess_history.TEMP_SPACE_ALLOCATED to see sessions/SQL use of TEMP

Example code for 1:

```
 with temp_blocksize as 
(
SELECT B.ts#, b.name, C.block_size, SUM (C.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 mb_total
FROM v$tablespace B, v$tempfile C
WHERE 1=1
and B.ts#= C.ts# (+)
and b.name like 'TEMP%'
GROUP BY B.ts#, b.name, C.block_size
)
select * from 
(
select tablespace_id
, name Tablespace_name
, (tablespace_maxsize * block_size ) / 1024 / 1024 tablespace_maxsize_mb
, round((tablespace_size * block_size) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) tablespace_size_gb
, round((tablespace_usedsize * block_size) / 1024 / 1024/ 1024, 2) tablespace_usedsize_gb
, tablespace_size
, tablespace_usedsize
, round((tablespace_usedsize/tablespace_size)*100, 2) used_pct
, rtime 
, awr.snap_id
from dba_hist_tbspc_space_usage where 1=1
   and awr.tablespace_id = blk.ts#
)
where used_pct > = nvl(:used_pct, 0)
          and (to_number(to_char(to_date(rtime, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24')) between nvl(:begin_hour, 0) and  nvl(:end_hour, 24) 
            or to_number(to_char(to_date(rtime, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24')) between nvl(:begin_hour2, nvl(:begin_hour, 0)) and  nvl(:end_hour2, nvl(:end_hour, 24)))

order by  rtime desc
;
```

Example code for 2:

```
    with tmp_usage as
(
select sql_id, sql_plan_hash_value, session_id, session_serial#
, min(user_id) user_id
, min(sample_time) min_sample_time, max(sample_time) max_sample_time
, max(sample_time) - min(sample_time) delta_time
, min(snap_id) min_snap_id, max(snap_id) max_snap_id
, round(max(temp_space_allocated) / (1024 * 1024)) Temp_usage_meg
, round(max(pga_allocated) / (1024 * 1024)) PGA_usage_meg
, sum(decode(event, 'direct path read temp', 1, 0) ) cnt_direct_path_read_temp
, sum(decode(event, 'direct path write temp', 1, 0) ) cnt_direct_path_write_temp
, sum(decode(event, null, 1, 0) ) cnt_ON_CPU
, count(*) - sum(decode(event, 'direct path read temp', 1, 0) ) - sum(decode(event, 'direct path write temp', 1, 0) ) - sum(decode(event, null, 1, 0) ) cnt_other
, count(*) cnt_sample
from dba_hist_active_sess_history ash
where temp_space_allocated is not null
  and session_id = nvl(:session_id, session_id)
  and session_serial# = nvl(:session_serial#, session_serial#)
  and trunc(sample_time, 'MI') between to_date(nvl(:sam_tm_str_MM_DD_YYYY_HH24_MI, to_char(sample_time, 'MM_DD_YYYY_HH24_MI')),'MM_DD_YYYY_HH24_MI') 
                      and to_date(nvl(:sam_tm_end_MM_DD_YYYY_HH24_MI, to_char(sample_time, 'MM_DD_YYYY_HH24_MI')),'MM_DD_YYYY_HH24_MI')
  and decode(:today_only_Y_N,'Y', sample_time, trunc(sysdate) ) >= trunc(sysdate)
  and nvl(upper(module),'x') like nvl(upper(:module), nvl(upper(module),'x')) 
  and nvl(machine,'x') like nvl(:machine, nvl(machine,'x')) 
  and nvl(program,'x') like nvl(:program, nvl(program,'x')) 
  and nvl(sql_id,'x') = nvl(:sql_id, nvl(sql_id,'x'))
group by sql_id, sql_plan_hash_value, session_id, session_serial#
order by max(temp_space_allocated) desc
)
select tmp.*
, (select username from dba_users du where du.user_id = tmp.user_id) username
, (select max(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(sql_text, 3800)) from dba_hist_sqltext st where st.sql_id = tmp.sql_id) sql_text
from tmp_usage tmp
where 1=1
  and rownum <= nvl(:top_n, 10)
order by 
case when :ord_temp = 'TEMP' then Temp_usage_meg 
     when :ord_temp = 'SNAP' then min_snap_id 
     else  Temp_usage_meg 
end 
desc
;
```

---

If you don't have the Diagnostics Pack license you can get the information from v$sort_usage, but you'll have to persist the information periodically to get a historic report.

Comment: If you don't have the Diagnostics Pack license you can get the information from v$sort_usage, but you'll have to persist the information periodically to get a historic report.